# Reading byte by byte in java

Tags: java, multithreading, image, block, bmp

I am trying to use threading on the reading of a bmp image in Java. More exactly, i want to read it in 4 chunks of data. This is for educational purposes only, i know it's not something you would technically need.
However, i don't know how to read the file byte by byte or chunk by chunk. The only thing i found was using readAllBytes which is not what i need, or readByte, which requires me having the array of bytes already, but this is not a threaded reading anymore.
Is there any way i could read byte by byte or block by block for a given path?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: use a `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);`and then `int val = fis.read()`on it. val == -1 signals end of file.

Comment: Do  you want to create for example 4 threads and read four different part of the image in 4 different thread?

Comment: @mahfujasif Yes! I am a beginner in Java and i don't know how to do that, i've been struggling for a bit because i don't even know for sure if it's possible. I am using the producer to read in chunks and the consumer to write it in the final variable of the file.

Comment: @JayC667  Thank you for responding! Who is file in this example, if it's the array of bytes in the image, doesn't that mean that i should already have the image ( the array) read? I am trying to only pass the path in order to only read it by chunks.

Answer (score 1):

`.read()`, with no arguments, reads exactly one byte, but two important notes on this:

1. This is not thread safe. Threading + disk generally doesn't work; the bottleneck is the disk, not the CPU, and you need to add a guard that only one thread is reading at any one time. Given that the disk is so slow, you'll end up in a situation that one thread needs to read from disk, does so, and processes the data so received, and while that is happening, the other X threads that all were waiting on disk now have one of them that can 'go' (the others still have to wait). But, each thread is done reading *and* processing data before any other thread even got unpaused: You gain nothing.
2. `read()` on a FileInputStream is usually *incredibly* slow. These are low level operations, but disks tend to read entire blocks at a time and are incapable of reading one byte at a time. Thus, `read()` is implemented as: Read the smallest chunk one can read (usually still 4096 or more bytes), take the one byte from that chunk that is needed, *and just toss the remainder in the garbage can*. In other words, if you read a file by calling `.read()` 4906 times, that reads the same chunk from disk 4096 times. Whereas calling:

```
byte[] b = new byte[4096];
int read = fileIn.read(b);
```

would fill the entire byte array with the chunk, and is thus 4096x faster.

If your aim is to learn about multithreading, 'reading a file' is not how to learn about it; you can't observe anything meaningful in action this way.

If your aim is to speed up BMP processing, 'multithread the reading process' is now the way either. I'm at a loss to explain why multithreading is involved here at all. It is suitable neither to learn about it, nor to speed anything up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, i will try and use your approach! This example was given to us by our professor, we have to build an image filter where the reading of the image is done with threads. It's very slow but i don't know how to do it in another way.

Comment: Just a queston, sorry! Who is fileIn in this example, is it a ByteArrayInputStream or a DataInputStream? And also, wouldn't this require having the file already written in fileIn? I am trying to only pass the path and read directly from there. Is that possible?